# Script's function works correctly on resize but not on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have a function that corrects and adapts the size (and vertical alignment) of three fluid columns with text and images.

The script, while not polished/efficient yet, works exactly as expected but sometimes(?) fails  at the beginning.

The functions is the following:

```
var resetHeight = function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".same-height-col").height("auto").each(function(){
        maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
    }).height(maxHeight + 25);
    var maxTextSize = 0;
    var tempHeight;
    $(".same-height-col").each(function(){
        tempHeight = $(this).find(".links-text").height();
        maxTextSize = tempHeight > maxTextSize ? tempHeight : maxTextSize;
    });
    var topMargin;
    $(".same-height-col").each(function(){
        topMargin = (maxTextSize - $(this).find(".links-text").height()) + 25;
        $(this).find(".links-image").css("margin-top",topMargin);
    });
}
```

The I call it twice:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    resetHeight();    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resetHeight();
    });   
});
```

The problem is that many times when I load the page, I see this:

[image]

That doesn't happen consistently, but it does happen pretty often, but as soon as I resize the window the script works exactly as expected:

[image]

So where could the mistake be?

The script is called for sure even at the beginning, if I put an alert in the function, and just load the page (with no resize), the alert pops up.

Comment: Can I see your HTML? Do your images have a set size inline? If not, they are 0x0 until they load

Comment: Are you running this script on the server, or is this a userscript?

Comment: @KatCox I'm running it on the server. http://www-beta.bikenatureguide.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the *maxHeight* value, you reset all the inline heights that were set in the previous resetHeight call by doing `$(".same-height-col").height("auto")`. However, you don't reset the *margin-top* properties that were added to the *links-image* elements.

This means that the second time that resetHeight is called (and all subsequent times), the *maxHeight* calculations will be different. To make sure the results are the same each time, you need to reset the *margin-top* property on the *links-image* elements before doing the calculation.

```
$(".same-height-col .links-image").css("margin-top","");
$(".same-height-col").height("auto").each(function(){
    maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
}).height(maxHeight + 25);
```

You may also want to make that height `maxHeight+50` rather than `maxHeight+25` if you think the result of the layout after the resize looked better than the intial layout on load.

Comment: This solved it! Thanks a bunch! I'll assign the bounty in 10 minutes, you deserve it :)

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your issue, you should set attribute width and height of images and use the document ready handler:

HTML for all images in `.links-image` DIVs: {width/height/alt attributes should always be specified for image when possible}

```
<div class="links-image" style="margin-top: 53px;">
    <img src="img/list.png" width="210" height="92" alt="">
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(resetHeight).trigger('resize');   
});
```

Comment: This is getting weirder, now at least it's consistently semi-broken, now every time I load I see this http://i.imgur.com/SjDezUr.png and after resize is see: http://i.imgur.com/4cSRqxq.png (which is the correct).

Comment: You should maybe provide an online link to let us see what issue is.

Comment: Sure! http://www-beta.bikenatureguide.org/ this is the live beta version, this is the location of the script http://www-beta.bikenatureguide.org/js/site.js

Comment: I'm still having no luck, I'm really confused as to what this may be.

Comment: @JanDvorak what browser are you using? Just in case, if you hard refresh, and then resize the window, you see no difference?

Comment: @JanDvorak Adding the width and height to the images fixed the biggest problem with the initial size calculation. The reason for the remaining difference between the intial load and the resize is explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I’m starting with the premise that you want the box content components — the title, the subtitle, and the image — vertically aligned across all the three boxes. If this is not true, just ignore this answer.

While I can’t spot the issue in the code at hand, I would try to approach it another way, without JS: clearfix the columns and fix the height of the components: let’s say I expect titles to be one line of text, subtitles three lines, and images are already fixed-height.

The fixed height will give you vertical alignment, and the clearfix will take care of the column height.